# JQuery: (window).resize works, (document).ready doesn't

Tags: jquery

I am having some issues getting this JQuery script to work. It works flawlessly when resizing the image, but I can't get this to work on the initial page load. Any ideas? I'm completely stuck and nothing is working for me.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($(window).width() <= 600) {
                $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
            } else if ($(window).width() < 748) {
                $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
            } else {
                $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($(document).width() <= 600) {
                $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
            } else if ($(window).width() < 748) {
                $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
            } else {
                $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just because the DOM is ready, doesn't mean images have loaded.

Comment: Why do you write the same exact function twice?

Comment: @techfoobar: I'd assume for the sake of the example.  He's saying the 1st one works, but not the 2nd.

Comment: I'm also relatively new to using Javascript and JQuery. Something I neglected for far too long. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments, document.ready != window.onload. Document.ready will not wait for the images to actually load. Thus, it can give bad results. You should hook into the window.onload event when you want to wait for images to fully finish (this is also the mechanism used in parallax sites which need to wait for images to load).

```
window.onload = function () {
        if ($(document).width() <= 600) {
            $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
        } else if ($(window).width() < 748) {
            $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
        } else {
            $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
        }
};
```

Comment: Ah, I fully understand. I'm looking through my notes because I swear I tried window.onload first. Ah well, this works perfectly. This is basic javascript, correct, not JQuery?

Comment: @MichaelStenberg - jQuery is javascript :). However, `window.onload` is part of the "vanilla" javascript API so it would require no libraries or included scripts to use.

Comment: That's what I mean. Thank you for your example and explanation!

Comment: Or `$(window).load(function(){});` :-)